# Overriding hashCode with overridden equals using equalsIgnoreCase to check equality

Tags: java, overriding, equals, hashcode

I've currently got an overridden `equals(Object)` that looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (! (o instanceof Player)) return false;
    Player p = (Player) o;
    return getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(p.getFirstName()) && 
            getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(p.getLastName());
}
```

My `hashCode()` currently looks like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    result = 31 * result + getFirstName().toLowerCase().hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + getLastName().toLowerCase().hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

My question is regarding my overridden hashCode() method. I know that I need hashCode() to return the same value for two objects if they are considered equal by the equals(Object) method. My gut tells me there is *some* case where this hashCode() will violate the contract.

Is there an acceptable way to use the equalsIgnoreCase(String) method in an overridden equals(Object) method and generate a hashcode that doesn't violate the contract?

Comment: In hashCode() result = 31... should be result *= 31... so you don't lose the value already in there.

Comment: He has result in the equation, 31 * result + (otherstuff). So it isn't lost. Just my 2 cents, but I think you're going at it the right way. Your equals method looks good to me.

Comment: Why would your code violate the contract? Your gut must be nervous, don't listen to it ;)

Comment: I might just be a little on the overly-cautious side, but I'm not entirely sure how the equalsIgnoreCase() and toLowerCase() methods works with special characters and differing locales. I don't think that will apply for this application, but I'm trying to do things as bullet-proof as possible to develop that habit.

Comment: Conventional wisdom is that you should never rely on the default `Locale`, but should always use `String.toLowerCase(Locale)` with an explicit `Locale`.  Otherwise you hit the "infamous Turkish Locale bug".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    result = 31 * result + characterwiseCaseNormalize(getFirstName()).hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + characterwiseCaseNormalize(getLastName()).hashCode();
    return result;
}

private static String characterwiseCaseNormalize(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    for(int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        sb.setCharAt(i,Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(i))));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This `hashCode` will be consistent with an `equals` defined using `equalsIgnoreCase`.  In principle, according to the contract of `equalsIgnoreCase`, this seems to rely on it being the case that

```
Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(c1))==Character.toLowerCase(Character.toUpperCase(c2))
```

whenever

```
Character.toLowerCase(c1)==Character.toLowerCase(c2).
```

I don't have proof that that is true, but the [OpenJDK implementation of equalsIgnoreCase](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.regionMatches%28boolean%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Cint%29) actually does it consistently with this method; it checks whether corresponding characters are equals, then whether their upper case versions are equals, then whether *the lower case versions of the upper case versions* are equal.

Comment: And `String.compareToIgnoreCase` uses this method explicitly.

Comment: I'll +1 for a new approach, but you should be really careful.  The Javadocs even warn you: `In general, String.toLowerCase() should be used to map characters to lowercase. String case mapping methods have several benefits over Character case mapping methods. String case mapping methods can perform locale-sensitive mappings, context-sensitive mappings, and 1:M character mappings, whereas the Character case mapping methods cannot.`  Plus this behavior doesn't seem guaranteed by the spec, so it may change out from other you.  Caution!

Comment: Right... I would say `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` (and `String.compareToIgnoreCase()`), being based on the `Character` case-mapping methods, should come with the same caveat.  In terms of writing a `hashCode()` consistent with `equals()`, you should either use `Character`-based case-mapping in both, or `String`-based case-mapping in both.  In fact, the original questioner may really want to keep his `hashCode()` method and change his `equals()` method to use `s1.toLowerCase().equals(s2.toLowerCase())` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. We can loop through all one-char strings, and find pairs `s1,s2` that `s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2) && !s1.toLowerCase().equals(s2.toLowerCase())`. There are quite some pairs. For example

```
s1=0049   'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I'
s2=0131   'LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I'

s1.lowercase = 0069   'LATIN SMALL LETTER I'
s2.lowercase = 0131   itself
```

It also depends on locale: for s1, *Turkish and Azerbaijani use U+0131 for lowercase* ( see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0049/index.htm )

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be worried.  [Read the contract for `equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).

Two characters c1 and c2 are considered the same ignoring case if at least one of the following is true:

- The two characters are the same (as compared by the == operator)
- Applying the method Character.toUpperCase(char) to each character produces the same result
- Applying the method Character.toLowerCase(char) to each character produces the same result

So, if there is a character that is equal when converted to *upper* case but not the other way around, you will be in trouble.

Let's take the example of the German character [ß](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Substitution_and_all_caps), which turns into a [two character sequence `SS`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/df/index.htm) when converted to upper case.  That means that the string "ß" and "SS" are "equalsIgnoreCase" but will not have the same representation when converted to lower case!

So your approach here is broken.  Unfortunately, I am not sure that you will be able to design a hashCode that adequately expresses your need here.

Comment: So using the character ß as an example, if we had a player with the first/last name "ßilly ßob", comparing him to another player named "SSilly SSob" would make them be equal in the eyes of equalsIgnoreCase but then generate two different hashCodes (the problem).   Assuming this is 'okay' for my application, could we generate a hashCode that is equal when they are considered equal by equalsIgnoreCase by using toUpperCase where I was using toLowerCase?

Comment: I'm sure you could find a counterexample the other way too.

Comment: @Jazzer: Does `equalsIgnoreCase` define an equivalence relation, i.e. is it impossible to have three strings x, y, and z, such that x.equalsIgnoreCase(y) and y.equalsIgnoreCase(z), but not x.equalsIgnoreCase(z)?  By the sound of it, "ß".equalsIgnoreCase("SS") would be true, and "ss".equalsIgnoreCase("SS") would be true, but "ß".equalsIgnoreCase("ss") would be false.  To override `equals` with a function that does not implement an equivalence relation would be broken, even if `hashCode` always returned matching values for matching strings.

Comment: `"ß".equalsIgnoreCase("SS")` is false, because `equalsIgnoreCase` uses `Character.toUpperCase` and `Character.toLowerCase` instead of `String.toUpperCase` and `String.toLowerCase`.  This gives hope for a `hashCode` consistent with `equalsIgnoreCase`; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of writing a `hashCode()` consistent with `equals()`, you should either use `Character`-based case-mapping in both, or `String`-based case-mapping in both.  In my other answer I showed how to write a `hashCode()` using `Character`-based case-mapping; but there's another solution, which is to change `equals()` instead to use `String`-based case-mapping.  (Note that `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` uses `Character`-based case-mapping.)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (! (o instanceof Player)) return false;
    Player p = (Player) o;
    return getFirstName().toLowerCase().equals(p.getFirstName().toLowerCase()) && 
        getLastName().toLowerCase().equals(p.getLastName().toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: In some circumstances, in fact, you really want to use some fancy Unicode normalization on your Strings as well as case-folding.  See http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/normalization .

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if (o == this) {
      return true;
    }
   
   if (o == null) {
       return false;
   }

   if (! (o instanceof Player)) {
       return false;
   }

    Player p = (Player) o;

    return equalsIgnoreCase(this.getFirstName(), p.getFirstName())
           && 
           equalsIgnoreCase(this.getLastName(), p.getLastName());

}


public boolean equalsIgnoreCase (String s1, String s2) {

   if (s1 == null && s2 == null) {
        return true;
    }
        
    if (s1 != null) {
        return s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2);
    } else {
        return s2.equalsIgnoreCase(s1);
    }

}
```